# Unreadable Notebook: Unsupported JSON nbformat version 4 (supported version: 3)

Tags: json, ubuntu, ipython, ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook

I've just installed `IPython` 3.0 using `pip` on my laptop, which is running `Ubuntu` 14.04:

```
$ pip search ipython
ipython-cluster-helper    - Simplify IPython cluster start up and use for
                            multiple schedulers.
ipython                   - IPython: Productive Interactive Computing
  INSTALLED: 3.0.0 (latest)
```

However, when I go to use `IPython`, the terminal seems to think it's using version 1.2.1:

```
$ ipython
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 1.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]
```

What's worse is, when I go to open a notebook in JSON nbformat version 4, which `IPython` 3.0 supports, I get the following error:

```
Unreadable Notebook: Unsupported JSON nbformat version 4 (supported version: 3)
```

I've attempted to downgrade the notebook to version 3, using the command recommended by the `IPython` team, but that fails for me as well:

```
$ ipython nbconvert --to notebook --nbformat 3 1-intro-to-brian-neurons.ipynb 
. . .
[NbConvertApp] CRITICAL | Bad config encountered during initialization:
[NbConvertApp] CRITICAL | Unrecognized flag: '--nbformat'
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I should mention I've uninstalled all versions of `IPython` other than the current one from my laptop.

Comment: Do you have ipython installed from apt? That's likely to be an older version, which is what you're seeing. The `--nbformat` flag for nbconvert is new in IPython 3, so that error is what I'd expect from an older version too.

Comment: Naa, I installed using `pip`, as stated in the question.  I may have previously installed it using `apt-get`, but I uninstalled `IPython` before re-installing with `pip`.

Comment: Wait, ah, I think you may be right.  I just ran `apt-get remove ipython` -- which I hadn't done before -- I'd only run `pip uninstall ipython` -- and that found and removed `IPython` 1.2.

Comment: Yep, problem solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An older version of `IPython` was installed previously using `apt-get`. Remove the older version using `apt-get remove ipython`.

Answer (score 0):

`jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --nbformat=3 <file.ipynb>` worked for me. 
My local anaconda2 support version 4 but docker's ipython cannot.