# ImportError: cannot import name LinkExtractor

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting the following error in scrapy v 0.24.5

```
ImportError: cannot import name LinkExtractor
```

This happens when I do:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24788376/scrapy-error-cannot-import-name-link-extractor

Comment: You need to update your scrapy do `easy_install --upgrade Scrapy`

Comment: @Kasra I'm on 0.24.5 though. When I do pip install -U Scrapy, it says I am on the latest version.

Comment: @bumpkin perhaps you have multiple versions of `Scrapy` installed?  look at the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286152/ipython-unreadable-notebook-unsupported-json-nbformat-version-4-supported-ver).

Comment: Remove the python-scrapy if you have mistakenly  installed before.

Comment: @Jithin That was the answer! I had python-scrapy installed. Thank you.